# Capture return code of Console application in VBscript?

Tags: c#, vbscript, console, console-application

I am trying to return a success/error code using Environment.Exit function in console application. (0 for success, 1 for error). Now i want to capture this return code in vbscript and display the return code (e.g. WScript.Echo(returnCode)).

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: the console app is return in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Launching other programs from a script](http://wsh2.uw.hu/ch07e.html).

```
exitcode = WshShell.Run(strCommand, , true])
```

> If bWaitOnReturn is set to True, the Run method creates a new process,
>   executes the command, and waits until the process terminates. In this
>   case, the Run method returns the error code obtained from the
>   terminated process. If bWaitOnReturn is missing or is set to False,
>   Run returns the error code 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
errcode =  WshShell.Run("your program.exe",,true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your script you are running is called "**Canada**.vbs" and let's say the script that will return the code "**Mexico**.vbs".

CANADA.VBS Code (This is what you will run.):

```
Dim ExitCode
Dim Return
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell=CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

Dim Command
Command="Mexico.vbs"
Command=Chr(34) & Command & Chr (34)
ExitCode=WshShell.Run (Command, 1, True)

If ExitCode="1" Then
Return="Success"
ElseIf ExitCode="2" Then
Return="Failure"
Else
Return="Unknown"
End If

MsgBox Return
```

MEXICO.VBS Code (This is what Canada will run.):

```
Dim Success

Success=MsgBox ("Do you want to Succeed?",vbQuestion + vbYesNo,"Your Goals are good?")

success=success-7        'Vbyes=6 vbno=7. True=-1 False=0.

'The Above Code is only for demonstration purposes. You may set success in your own statement

If Success Then          'Successful
Success=1
ElseIf not Success Then  'Failure
Success=2
Else                     'Unknown
Success=0
End If

WScript.Quit (Success)
```

---

Ok now in Canada you will need to declare a variable that will hold the exit code of Mexico. Let's name it

 `Dim ExitCode`
We are also going to need a String Variable (Although you can double up the ExitCode variable as this but doing so could make debugging difficult with large files. so let's keep them seperate.)

```
Dim Return
```

and we are going to need an object that will run the Mexico.vbs. the object we need is the Wscript Shell

```
Dim WshShell
Set Wshshell=CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
```

Now we need to Specify the Script to run. the script path being "Mexico.vbs"

```
Dim Command
Command="Mexico.vbs"
```

Now JUST IN CASE there are any spaces in the filepath (there isn't but let's be safe) we need to enclose the path in quotes. (Character code: 34)

```
Command=Chr(34) & Command & Chr (34)
```

Now we need to run the Mexico.vbs from the Canada.vbs and save the return to a variable

```
ExitCode=WshShell.Run (Command, 1, True) 'command is path, 1 is window state, true is wait for return.
```

Now we format the ExitCode into an UserFriendly string.

```
If ExitCode="1" Then
Return="Success"
ElseIf ExitCode="2" Then
Return="Failure"
Else
Return="Unknown"
End If
```

Now we will display the Result in a msgbox.

```
MsgBox Return
```

---

In Mexico.vbs you will be sending the success or failure through an exit code.
We will name the exitcode variable Success

```
Dim Success
```

THIS PART IS FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES. You can exclude this portion and replace it with your auditing statements. Just set the Success to true if successful or False if Failure.

```
Success=MsgBox ("Do you want to Succeed?",vbQuestion + vbYesNo,"Your Goals are good?")

success=success-7        'Vbyes=6 vbno=7. True=-1 False=0.

'The Above Code is only for demonstration purposes. You may set success in your own statement
```

Now we will convert the bool Success into an Integer, 1=success,2=failure,0=unknown

```
If Success Then          'Successful
Success=1
ElseIf not Success Then  'Failure
Success=2
Else                     'Unknown
Success=0
End If
```

And now we will terminate the Mexico.vbs Script with the exit code set in Success.

```
WScript.Quit (Success)
```